# Erro ao tentar fazer download de zip da BMF com python

Tags: html, python, url, arquivo-zip

Estou tentando baixar de uma vez os arquivos zip da BMF (ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/), mas aparece um erro em que o programa não acha o arquivo, porém ele existe.

segue o código:

```
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd

startdate = '20150130'
enddate = '20150210'
extension = '.zip'
daterange = pd.date_range(startdate, enddate)

for single_date in daterange:
zipurl = 'ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_' + single_date.strftime('%Y%m%d') + extension
with urlopen(zipurl) as zipresp:
    with ZipFile(BytesIO(zipresp.read())) as zfile:
        zfile.extractall('C:/Users/.../.../...')
```

O erro que aparece é basicamente que ele não acha o arquivo...

> ftplib.error_perm: 550 NEG_BMF_20150131.zip: The system cannot find
>   the file specified..

Existe um jeito mais fácil de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está quase perfeito. Muito bom!

Resolvi testar seu código com as seguintes datas:

```
startdate = '20170130'
enddate = '20170207'
```

Ao testar com um período menor, pude perceber o seguinte:

- esse erro só aparece quando não ocorreram negócios no dia (sáb, dom ou feriados), ou seja, o arquivo realmente não existe!
- você pode utilizar uma estrutura try/except para contornar esse erro

**Código Exemplo:**

```
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd

startdate = '20170130'
enddate = '20170207'
extension = '.zip'
daterange = pd.date_range(start=startdate, end=enddate)

for single_date in daterange:
    zipurl = 'ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_' + single_date.strftime('%Y%m%d') + extension
    try:
        with urlopen(zipurl) as zipresp:
            with ZipFile(BytesIO(zipresp.read())) as zfile:
                zfile.extractall()
        print("OK: {}".format(zipurl))
    except:
        print('ERRO: {}'.format(zipurl))

    print("="*5)
```

**Output:**

```
OK: ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_20170130.zip
=====
OK: ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_20170131.zip
=====
OK: ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_20170201.zip
=====
OK: ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_20170202.zip
=====
OK: ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_20170203.zip
=====
ERRO: ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_20170204.zip
=====
ERRO: ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_20170205.zip
=====
OK: ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_20170206.zip
=====
OK: ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_20170207.zip
=====
```

---

Conferindo no calendário, podemos ver que `04/02/2017` foi um `sábado` e `05/02/2017` um `domingo`.

E ao entrar na pasta com os supostos downloads, surpresa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que retirei o caminho de output da extração p/ fins de teste. Pode reincluí-lo no seu código (`zfile.extractall('C:/Users/.../.../...')`)

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo uma estratégia diferente. Simplesmente baixo o que eles disponibilizam. Claro que mantenho controle do que já foi baixado para não baixar novamente.

Primeiramente listo os arquivos contidos em ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/:

```
import FTP

def listar_arquivos_ftp_bmf():    
    ftp = FTP('ftp.bmf.com.br') 
    ftp_dir = '/MarketData/BMF/'
    ftp.login()
    ftp.cwd(ftp_dir)
    arquivos = ftp.nlst()
    ftp.close()

    return arquivos
```

Depois baixo cada um dos arquivos:

```
import urllib

def baixar_arquivo(url, file_name, CHUNK = 16 * 1024):
    """
    url: caminho do arquivo que será baixado. String.
        Ex.: ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_YYYYMMDD.ZIP

    file_name: caminho e nome do arquivo que será salvo. String.
    """
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=120)

    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = response.read(CHUNK)
            if not chunk:
                break
            f.write(chunk)

    response.close()
```

Espero ter ajudo.

Possuo uma base grande, porém existe um buraco. Por um acaso você possui os arquivos NEG_BMF_YYYYMMDD.ZIP dos meses de Fevereiro, Março, Abril e Maio de 2017? Pode disponibilizá-los?

Obrigado.