# Descompactar arquivo .gz com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

Estou  utilizando o código abaixo que peguei [neste endereço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197686/erro-ao-tentar-fazer-download-de-zip-da-bmf-com-python).

Porém não estou conseguindo descompactar arquivos `.gz`. Já tentei a biblioteca `tarfile`, porém sem sucesso.  Segue o código abaixo:

```
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd


startdate = '20170130'
enddate = '20170207'
extension = '.zip'
daterange = pd.date_range(start=startdate, end=enddate)

for single_date in daterange:
   zipurl = 'ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/BMF/NEG_BMF_' + 
single_date.strftime('%Y%m%d') + extension
   try:
      with urlopen(zipurl) as zipresp:
          with ZipFile(BytesIO(zipresp.read())) as zfile:
              zfile.extractall()
      print("OK: {}".format(zipurl))
   except:
      print('ERRO: {}'.format(zipurl))

   print("="*5)
```

Comment: Qual erro que aparece?

Comment: Tenho que descompactar arquivos .gz.  E esse código  descompacta .zip.   Tentei substituir  por gz, mas não deu certo.  Erros de programação mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso utilizando as bibliotecas **gzip** e **shutil**, como no exemplo:

```
import gzip
import shutil

with gzip.open('file.gz', 'rb') as entrada:
    with open('file', 'wb') as saida:
        shutil.copyfileobj(entrada, saida)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu certo.

Comment: Perfeito, Heber!